# Problem with CreateDC of printer after call PageSetupDlg() function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, printing, windows-ce

I am working with project in C++ WinAPI for WindowsCE 2013.
IDE which I use is Visual Studio 2013
I firstly initialize a PageSetupDialog in my application..
Screen below:
[image]

Unfortunately I still have problem with start printing.
I have assumption that problem is in CreateDC that the values from DialogBox are not forwarded to CreateDC function.
I read in that documentation that PageSetupDlg function return DEVMODE structure, but I have no idea how to forward that to Create DC function. Thanks for Your help in this matter.
I put definition of responsible function:

> ```
> BOOL OknoDrukowania(HWND hWnd)
> {
>     PAGESETUPDLG psd;   
>     DEVMODE dm;// common dialog box structure
>     // Initialize PAGESETUPDLG
>     ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
>     psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd);
>     psd.hwndOwner = hWnd;
>     psd.hDevMode = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
>     psd.hDevNames = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
>     psd.Flags = PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES | PSD_MARGINS ;
>     psd.rtMargin.top = 1000;
>     psd.rtMargin.left = 1250;
>     psd.rtMargin.right = 1250;
>     psd.rtMargin.bottom = 1000;
>     //psd.lpfnPagePaintHook = PaintHook;
>  
>     if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
>     {
>         HDC hDC;
>         hDC = CreateDC(NULL, dm.dmDeviceName, NULL, NULL);
>         StartDoc(hDC, NULL);
>         StartPage(hDC);
>         Ellipse(hDC, 500, 500, 1000, 1000);
>         Ellipse(hDC, 1000, 800, 1500, 1300);
>         Ellipse(hDC, 800, 1000, 1800, 2000);
>         EndPage(hDC);
>         EndDoc(hDC);
>         DeleteDC(hDC);  // check paper size and margin values here.
>     }
>     return TRUE;
>  
> }
> ```

Comment: `CreateDC` is not a good way to create a printer DC.  The idiomatic way to do it is via [`PrintDlg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms646940(v=vs.85)) or [`PrintDlgEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms646942(v=vs.85)).

Comment: @PaulSanders follow with Microsoft documentation PrintDlg and PrintDlgEx is not supported for WindowsCE 2013. For WindowsCE 2.10 and later PrintDlg function was replaced with PageSetupDlg which i use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ee504830%28v%3dwinembedded.60%29

Comment: Ah, good point.  I retract my statement.  In that case, pass a pointer to the `DEVMODE` structure as the 4th parameter to `CreateDC` as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms908168(v=msdn.10))

Comment: What is the return value of `CreateDC`? If it is NULL, use `GetLastError` to view the system error code. And is `dm.dmDeviceName` a valid value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by this fragment of code:

```
memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        HDC hDC;
        hDC = CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, &dm);
```